# Table automatically center along

Tags: html, html-table

I have normal table, nothing special about it, here it is:

### live example : http://jsfiddle.net/fFENK/1/

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td colspan="2">$10s0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>$100 <br/>$100 <br/>$100 <br/> </td>
    <td>$540</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem here is the text that got automatically centered along, as you can see in the live example I gave before, the text "January" is in the middle of the cell and not at the top of the cell like it suppose to be. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Add some css to your code:

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `valign` attribute to `<td>` node:

```
<td rowspan="2" valign="top">January</td>
```

Comment: That was superseded by CSS over a decade ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this css to make it get to the top

```
td { vertical-align: top }
```